# Open Android app (bring to front) when notification received

Tags: android

I have a simple React Native app, with a single activity `MainActivity`. The app is meant to be used for an online orders system, so it's meant to be "on" all the time. When the app receives a notification I want to open the app if killed, and bring to the foreground if in background. I have made this work in the past with the example code below but it doesn't work anymore, I don't know if it's an Android API change or what. Please also note I'm not an Android developer so bear that in mind.

I'm using OneSignal and here is my notification received handler:

```
public class SignalReceiver implements OneSignal.OSRemoteNotificationReceivedHandler  {
  @Override
  public void remoteNotificationReceived(Context context, OSNotificationReceivedEvent notification) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        context.startActivity(intent);
        Log.d("ONESIGNAL", "OPENED??");
  }
}
```

and this is my `AndroidManifest.xml` excerpt. The only relevant part should be the `<meta-data>` tag as that was added as per OneSignal documentation, but pasting other parts in case relevant:

```
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationServiceExtension"
    android:value="com.packagename.SignalReceiver"
  />
</application>
```

The log message display in Logcat in Android Studio so the code is running all fine. I also get a notification 30 seconds after the log shows, so that is also very odd!

I have noticed `com.onesignal.NotificationServiceExtension` doesn't actually exist if I try to import in code, but I don't know if it's meant to.

Can someone see any problem with my code, and if yes how can I get it to bring the app to foreground?

**Edit**

I've tried this code in Android versions 11 and 12 on Samsung devices. Standard devices, not kiosk or managed.

I also just noticed if the app has been closed for a few minutes (over 5 minutes) then the app does indeed open up. But not if it's been used recently.

Comment: You should mention what devices/OS version you tested on prior.  Also check if app is running on a [managed device](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices) or kiosk mode on older version of OS.

Comment: Thanks @MorrisonChang I added a couple of edits at the bottom.

Comment: FYI: [Restrictions on starting activities from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) and [Android bring app to foreground on Firebase notification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65476441/295004)